# Improving a PHP function

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

I am using a switch-function for exception strings, which should be changed for the correct h1-titles and so on.

My goal is to have fewer exception for the `function ausnahme`.

```
function ausnahme($value) {
    global $value; // now the function ausnahme may change the variable
    switch ($value) {
        case "kern teilchenphysik": $value = "Kern-/Teilchenphysik";
            break;
        case "tipps tricks": $value = "Tipps & Tricks";
            break;
        case "erich honecker": $value = "Erich Honecker";   
            break;
        case "&ouml;kogeographische regeln": $value = "Ökogeographische Regeln";
        break;              
    }
    return $value;
}
```

This switch has now 3000 lines and I would like rules before this switch in the function.

Example: To erase all switch-terms with 2 words or better x-words, which should all start with a capital letter I would like my function bigwords:

example: two-words -> Two Words, three-words-expression -> Three Words Expression

Some words should not be allowed to capitalize like 'und','das';'der','die' etc.

```
function bigwords($value) {
    global $value;
    $value = "X" . $value;
// Hilfsvariable,da & sonst auf Position 0 steht,
// was gleichbedeutend mit FALSE/NULL angesehen wird
    if (strpos($value, "&a") == "1") {
        $value = substr($value, 2);
        $value = "&" . ucfirst($value);
    } elseif (strpos($value, "&o") == "1") {
        $value = substr($value, 2);
        $value = "&" . ucfirst($value);
    } elseif (strpos($value, "&u") == "1") {
        $value = substr($value, 2);
        $value = "&" . ucfirst($value);
    } else {
        // X wieder entfernen
        $value = substr($value, 1);
        $value = ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

I could delete  many switch-lines with this part before the switch, because for some other cases are different or expection of an exception I would called it ;-).
Another problem are german umlauts:

Example: 'oeffnung-boerse-oekologie' is now: 'Öffnung börse ökologie'
I want with `function bigwords` and `function umlaute`  to achieve: 'Öffnung Börse Ökologie'.

```
function umlaute($value) {
    global $value;      // 12.07.14 str_replace changed from eregi_replace/ 22.07.14 mehrere str_replace mit arrays geändert
    $from = ['-', 'ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'Ae', 'Oe', 'Ue'];
    $to = [' ', '&auml;', '&ouml;', '&uuml;', '&Auml;', '&Ouml;', '&Uuml'];
    $value = mb_strtolower(str_replace($from, $to, $value), 'utf-8');
// ACHTUNG! Dadurch greift die "erster Buchstabe Groß"-Regel nicht mehr, da erster
// "Buchstabe" nun das Kaufmanns-Und ist! -> wird in bigwords ersetzt
}
```

// the last 2 comments maybe outdated, because the bigwords-rule works with this function I think. My former programmer writes the script things the first letter is an '&' not a letter anymore after this function.

Feel free to give my hints for the existing `function bigwords` and `function umlaute`
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input for your switch and tell us what are you trying to achieve with your function. Because I don't understand your terms: "delete many switch-lines", "x-words".

Comment: So why is a global `$value` not just set to what you need in the first place? You are setting it to that any ways. Take a look at the overall architecture though you may want to create a page class that can hold the needed page elements for you.

Comment: Please don't pass variables to functions and then access them `global`. That doesn't make sense. Just pass the variables [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: would suggest to pass $value on reference like &$value. This should mean that you can get rid of the global.

Comment: @simon I know `global` shouldn't be used, but I don't know how the different functions should work without it. In my big function_inc.php file, where `function ausnahme` and many more I found 8times global :-(.

Comment: @user4035 I thought I have some sample inputs in my question like 'oeffnung-boerse-oekologie' is now 'Öffnung börse ökologie' and should be 'Öffnung Börse Ökologie'.  The bigwords function only works for the first word. I would like to add to the `function bigwords` rules for expressions with more than one word like 2,3 etc. In the ausnahme-function different kind of examples should disregard this function, if the second or any word shouldn't be capitalize or something else like in the switch function.

Comment: @Grischa "I know global shouldn't be used, but I don't know how the different functions should work without it." - they pass parameters to each other.

Comment: @user4035 and @Bas Slats I have replaced `global` with adding an `&` to the variable to all three functions and everything works like before. Thank you! I will not change the code in this question. So how to change not only the first string in the variable?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, this should do the trick:

```
<?php 

$noUpper = [];
foreach (
    ['und','das','der','die']
    as $k
) $noUpper[$k] = true;
function prettify($inStr){
    global $noUpper;
    $out = [];
    foreach (
        explode(" ", $inStr)
        as $chunk
    ) array_push($out, @ $noUpper[$chunk] ? $chunk : ucfirst($chunk));
    return htmlentities(implode(" ", $out));
};

echo prettify("hello und me no das & der die"); // Sorry: I don't understand German ;-)

// Output: "Hello und Me No das &amp; der die"
```

For the html entities translation I used existing htmlentities() php function.

**EDIT:**

New version with the modifications mentioned in comments:

```
<?php 

function prettify($inStr){

    static $noUpper;
    if (is_null($noUpper)) { // Messy static trick
        $noUpper = [];
        foreach (
            ['und','das','der','die']
            as $k
        ) $noUpper[$k] = true;
    };

    $out = [];
    foreach (
        explode("-", $inStr)
        as $chunk
    ) array_push($out, @ $noUpper[$chunk] ? $chunk : ucfirst($chunk));
    return htmlentities(implode(" ", $out));
};

echo prettify("hello-und-me-no-das-&-der-die"); // Sorry: I don't understand German ;-)

// Output: "Hello und Me No das &amp; der die"
```

...and, just as an example of (good) closure based implementation, this would be the same implementation in javascript:

```
"use strict";
var prettify = (function(){
    // Notice, this is only internally visible scope.
    var noUpper = {};
    for (
        let k of ['und','das','der','die']
    ) noUpper[k] = true;
    function htmlentities(str){
        // There is no native php htmlentities() equivalent in javascript.
        // So should implement it or rely on existing implementations in external
        // modules such underscore.
        // I left it empty because it is only for explanatory purposes.
        return str.replace("&", "&amp;"); // (Just to match PHP example...)
    };

    // ...and below function would be the only thing visible (exposed) outside.
    return function prettify_implementation(inStr){
        return htmlentities(inStr
            .split("-")
            .map(function(chunk){
                chunk = chunk.toLowerCase();
                return noUpper[chunk]
                    ? chunk
                    : chunk.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        +chunk.substring(1)
                ;       
            })  
            .join(" ")
        );  

    };
})();

console.log(prettify("hello-und-me-no-das-&-der-die")); // Sorry: I don't understand German ;-)

// Output: "Hello und Me No das &amp; der die"
```

Comment: I think maybe a working solution. 2 questions: Is it a good way to use `global`? Where to put your function and should I rename `$inStr` in `$value`. Your example isn't like mines. Every word are seperatre with '-' like in your example 'hello-und-me-no-das-&-der-die'. Please add example outputs like echo prettify("oeffnung-boerse-und-oekologie"); which should have the output: 'Öffnung Böerse und Ökologie. Maybe the function need somewhere "UTF-8".

Comment: Q1: Definetively not!! Even using php itself if you can choice also isn't good idea :-P. I simply had'nt too much time and had to choice between eficiency and elegance ;-). Alternatively you can use the `['und' => true, 'das' => true, ...]` solution inside the function or simply move its building foreach inside (but this implies to rebuild it every time it is called).

The right solution is to use a closure. Latest PHP versions theorically comes with closures, but what I saw seemed to me a mess (and I'm not sure if it could be useful for this at all...).

Comment: ...So, at the end (in PHP) the better solution is to rely on (messy) static variable + if statment (I will uptate my answer ;-)).

Comment: Q2: As I said, I wrote it rapidly and I unconciously missed the fact you are separating by "-" instead of spaces ("-"). But it is as simple to fix as replacing that glue string in the `explode(...)` sentence before.

As a note, it is also possible to make it case insensitive (I figure out it could avoid some issues to you...) simply by applying `strtolower()` to each readed chunk. But I omitted that in the sake of brevity (and of making code cleaner to better explain just what you are asking for).

Comment: Thanks again for your EDIT, but unfortunately I didn't get any changes to `function prettify(&$value){` and changed the second `$inStr in `$value`.  I have also tried not to use my functions and then nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123369/discussion-between-grischa-and-bitifet).